# Host only works mac--> windows

Tags: macos, windows-10, synergy

I can connect my windows machine (client) to my mac (host) but not vice versa, when trying to connect the connection just times out, any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: How do you expect connecting to a client to work? Do you have any server software running on the client machine?

Comment: oh sorry I didn't Specify, I am using the software "synergy"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Windows 7 on previous versions of Synergy when trying to have my Windows 7 laptop be the master and my Macbook Pro be the slave. It would only work if I made the Macbook Pro the master. I eventually updated my windows and a new version of Synergy came out. One of these two things fixed the issue for me. I never had this problem on my windows 10 gaming PC.